# Viewing awarded badges seems to be inconsistent

Tags: support, badges

I was recently awarded both [Excavator](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/1287/excavator?userid=156755) and a second [Yearling](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/13/yearling?userid=156755)

When viewing the excavator, I see something like this:

```
[Badge] Edited first post that was inactive for 6 months.
Basiclife earned this badge 1 time
4h ago Setting external application focus
[Link]Others with this badge[/Link]
```

but the yearling badge simply shows this:

```
[Badge] Active member for a year, earning at least 200 reputation. This badge can be awarded multiple times.
58455 Users earned this badge. Recently awarded to:
```

Where can I find out how many times I've been awarded `Yearling` (I'm guessing 2 as I've been active on SO for 2 years but I had to check my profile to see how long I'd been on the site)

I've tagged this support as it's likely a user error not a bug.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Look in your [user profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/156755/basiclife), down at the bottom.

[image: Yearling x 2]

Comment: Thanks, that answers my initial question. That said, is there a reason the 2 badges are displayed differently by default?

Comment: One badge is linked to posts. The other is not. @bas